# Почему не действует правило css на кнопку формы обратной связи?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по форме обратной связи.
Пытаюсь подцепить в нее данные из чекбокса (пока только кнопка "Медь микс"), но не происходит никаких действий по щелчку на ней, и в уведомлении на почту приходят только указанные "Имя" и "Телефон", а также пропала анимация, которая есть на других кнопках.

https://jsfiddle.net/ew16xa97/

p.s. css файл целиком по ссылке на фиддл.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<h2>Checkboxes</h2>
<form class="work-request">
  <div class="work-request--options">
    <span class="options-a">
                <input type="checkbox" name="opt-1" value="Медь микс"><br>
                <label for="opt-1">
                  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                  viewBox="0 0 150 111" style="enable-background:new 0 0 150 111;" xml:space="preserve">
                  <g transform="translate(0.000000,111.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
                    <path d="M950,705L555,310L360,505C253,612,160,700,155,700c-6,0-44-34-85-75l-75-75l278-278L550-5l475,475c261,261,475,480,475,485c0,13-132,145-145,145C1349,1100,1167,922,950,705z"/>
                  </g>
                  </svg>
                  Медь микс
                </label>
                <input id="opt-2" type="checkbox" value="АКБ">
                <label for="opt-2">
                  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                  viewBox="0 0 150 111" style="enable-background:new 0 0 150 111;" xml:space="preserve">
                  <g transform="translate(0.000000,111.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
                    <path d="M950,705L555,310L360,505C253,612,160,700,155,700c-6,0-44-34-85-75l-75-75l278-278L550-5l475,475c261,261,475,480,475,485c0,13-132,145-145,145C1349,1100,1167,922,950,705z"/>
                  </g>
                  </svg>
                  АКБ
                </label>
                <input id="opt-3" type="checkbox" value="Алюминий банка">
                <label for="opt-3">
                  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                  viewBox="0 0 150 111" style="enable-background:new 0 0 150 111;" xml:space="preserve">
                  <g transform="translate(0.000000,111.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
                    <path d="M950,705L555,310L360,505C253,612,160,700,155,700c-6,0-44-34-85-75l-75-75l278-278L550-5l475,475c261,261,475,480,475,485c0,13-132,145-145,145C1349,1100,1167,922,950,705z"/>
                  </g>
                  </svg>
                  Алюминий банка
                </label>
              </span>
    <span class="options-b">
                <input id="opt-4" type="checkbox" value="Менее 100 кг">
                <label for="opt-4">
                  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                  viewBox="0 0 150 111" style="enable-background:new 0 0 150 111;" xml:space="preserve">
                  <g transform="translate(0.000000,111.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
                    <path d="M950,705L555,310L360,505C253,612,160,700,155,700c-6,0-44-34-85-75l-75-75l278-278L550-5l475,475c261,261,475,480,475,485c0,13-132,145-145,145C1349,1100,1167,922,950,705z"/>
                  </g>
                  </svg>
                  Менее 100 кг
                </label>
                <input id="opt-5" type="checkbox" value="Более 100 кг">
                <label for="opt-5">
                  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                  viewBox="0 0 150 111" style="enable-background:new 0 0 150 111;" xml:space="preserve">
                  <g transform="translate(0.000000,111.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
                    <path d="M950,705L555,310L360,505C253,612,160,700,155,700c-6,0-44-34-85-75l-75-75l278-278L550-5l475,475c261,261,475,480,475,485c0,13-132,145-145,145C1349,1100,1167,922,950,705z"/>
                  </g>
                  </svg>
                  Более 100 кг
                </label>
                <input id="opt-6" type="checkbox" value="Нужен вывоз">
                <label for="opt-6">
                  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                  viewBox="0 0 150 111" style="enable-background:new 0 0 150 111;" xml:space="preserve">
                  <g transform="translate(0.000000,111.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
                    <path d="M950,705L555,310L360,505C253,612,160,700,155,700c-6,0-44-34-85-75l-75-75l278-278L550-5l475,475c261,261,475,480,475,485c0,13-132,145-145,145C1349,1100,1167,922,950,705z"/>
                  </g>
                  </svg>
                  Нужен вывоз
                </label>
              </span>
  </div>
  <div class="work-request--information">
    <div class="information-name">
      <input type="text" name="Имя" required>
      <label for="name">Имя</label>
    </div>
    <div class="information-phone">
      <input type="number" name="Телефон" required>
      <label for="phone">Телефон</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: Чтобы вернуть эффект на кнопке, нужно заменить: `<input type="checkbox" name="opt-1" value="Медь микс"><br>` на `<input type="checkbox" id="opt-1" value="Медь микс">`

Comment: Eleferen, это понятно, так и было изначально. Но что и где поменять, чтобы эффект был при новых условиях?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методом проб и ошибок решение оказалось простым - не много изменить эту строку:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="opt-1" value="Медь микс"><br>
<label for="opt-1">
```

на

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Медь" id="opt-1" value="Медь микс">
<label for="opt-1">
```